# How to get all information stored to a certain Google Maps Place ID?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I learned that if I search Google Maps with a certain keyword I get hits of Place IDs that seem to fit the keyword I entered. Now I wondered if it is possible to get all information stored to a certain Google Maps Place ID like for example `ChIJk5rNr3KuEmsRwWgFX9zzBaQ`. Preferably in JSON format.

Is that possible with the Google Maps API v3?

**Edit**: I found the possibility to get a list for certain information by doing this request

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

but there are definitely not all information listed.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Google Places API itself, your docs reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsRequests). Example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PLACE_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

If you are using PlacesService of Google Maps JS API, check [these docs](https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/) (section "Demos and sample code", tab "PLACE DETAILS"). Example:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
var request = {
    placeId: PLACE_ID
};
service.getDetails(request, function (place, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      console.log(place);
    }
});
```

Comment: The first link helped me, thanks! But maybe I add an example to my question. If I search for "farm shop" I do find some stores and private persons, that have been connected to the term "farm shop". But that has nothing to do with the `type` keywords like `food`. It's information Google seems to have in their database. For example with some Place IDs there is a description like "Bauernmarkt" that is no official keyword, take this place id for example: `ChIJO9TjQB0PdkcRreE0s1rNOdM`. If you follow the Link you'll see "Bauernmarkt" as descr. Do I get these information, or won't Google reveal them?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. But  maybe check this section of docs: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults it contains list of resutls you get with your data. There is name of the place and also types, which contains list of types (https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) which the place has assigned. Also if you scroll down under place details you can see that there are also some premium information.

Comment: To put it straight, I find places with search terms that are not publicly available within the place details.